# rails bootstrap css optimisation

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I have many tables and instead of always giving the class         `%table.table.table-hover.table-condensed.table-responsive.table-bordered` can I somehow set it as `%table` that will take all the other options from application.css.scss?

I tried

```
.table {
    .table-responsive;
    .table-bordered;
}
```

, but it shows wrong.

Any ideas?

Comment: How are you including Bootstrap in your Rails application? Via the [official](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass) gem or some other means?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@extend looks like the solution to your problem.
Add the following to your scss :

```
table {
  @extend .table, .table-hover, .table-condensed, .table-responsive, .table-bordered
}
```

Be careful, though : @extend is tricky and doesn't adds the properties from .table, .table-hover, etc to your definition of 'table', but rather adds the content of the block to all the places in your compiled css where any of the other classes are mentioned.

Comment: Works great, Thank you! & can you tell me how to move a button class to scss? I currently have `%td= link_to 'Show', product, class: 'btn btn-mini btn-success glyphicon glyphicon-search'`. I tried to put `class: 'button1'` & scss `@extend .btn, .btn-mini, btn-success, .glyphicon, .glyphicon-search`, but it did not work. Mb something with spaces?

Comment: You're using Bootstrap 2 ? I tried with the Bootstrap 3 equivalent `.button1 {@extend .btn, .btn-xs, .btn-success, .glyphicon, .glyphicon-search}`, it works fine. **Edit** you forgot a dot before btn-success, I don't see any other problem.

Comment: Works this way! The `.btn-mini` does not work, so I did without it

Comment: Great ! Could you please accept the answer, then ? :)